# Why doesn't "$S_n$ appears as a Galois group over $\Bbb{Q}$" wrap up the Inverse Galois Problem?

Tags: field-theory, soft-question, finite-groups, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Since every finite group $G$ is embedded in $S_n$ for $n = |G|$ and Hilbert showed that $S_n$ appears as a Galois group of $K/\Bbb{Q}$ for some Galois extension $K$, then how does that *not* wrap up the Inverse Galois Problem?

Why couldn't we somehow take any subgroup of $S_n$ and show that it must be the Galois group over $\Bbb{Q}$ of some $L \supset K$?

Comment: Do you mean $L\subset K?$ Don’t see how a bigger field gives a smaller group.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I thought things were inclusion-reversing here.

Comment: You've just proven that every group occurs as a Galois group of some extension $K/L$: if $H\subset S_n$ and $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q) = S_n$, then $H = \mathrm{Gal}(K/L)$ for some subfield $L$. The difficult bit is showing that we can take $L = \mathbb Q$.

Comment: Good question! Let's chat about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Subgroups $H$ of $Gal(E/F)$ correspond to intermediate fields $K$ where $H = Gal(E/K)$ Therefore, if we apply it to $F = \mathbb{Q}$, then all we can conclude is that $H$ is the Galois group of some field extension $E/K$, neither of which are required to be $\mathbb{Q}$.

To solve the inverse Galois problem, it is sufficient to show that every finite group is a **quotient** of $S_n$, not a subgroup.

Comment: It's probably useful to remark that most groups *aren't* quotients of $S_n$: for large $n$ ($n>6$?), the only nontrivial quotient of $S_n$ is the group of order $2$.